# use some python package for python agent

Tags: python, langchain, python-agent

Hi i want to use langchain python agent and openai, to use some

python packages. e.g. scanpy, and some python data object like adata.

```
agent_executor = create_python_agent(
    llm=openai_llm,
    tool=PythonAstREPLTool(locals={"adata": adata, "scanpy": sc} ),
    verbose=True,
    agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
)
```

but got error message like this one

`` However, since I cannot import external libraries like scanpy in this environment or access external data objects like `adata`, I cannot execute this task directly. ``

My question is how can I use package like scanpy with python agent, is that even possible?

Comment: @Grismar, thanks! you have a great point. Since I am completely rewrote the question. it is posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77557699/langchain-python-agent-response-quirky-behavior-reproducible-example