# langchain python agent response quirky behavior [reproducible example]

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

langchain python agent react differently, for one prompt, it can import scanpy library, but not for the other one. My question is how to make sure to import the correct library without problem.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
import openai
import os
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
from langchain_experimental.agents.agent_toolkits import create_python_agent
from langchain_experimental.tools import PythonREPLTool
import scanpy as sc

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]

agent_executor = create_python_agent(
    llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-4-1106-preview"),
    tool=PythonREPLTool(),
    verbose=True,
    agent_type=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
    agent_executor_kwargs={"handle_parsing_errors": True},
)
```

if run the following,
`agent_executor.run("set scanpy setting verbosity = 3 ")`

I get

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...

Invoking: Python_REPL with import scanpy as sc
sc.settings.verbosity = 3
print(sc.settings.verbosity)


3
The verbosity level of Scanpy has been set to 3.

> Finished chain.
The verbosity level of Scanpy has been set to 3.
```

but, if run the following,

```
pbmc = sc.datasets.pbmc68k_reduced()
agent_executor.run("use 'scanpy' library and 'pbmc' object to plot a umap")
```

I get,

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Python REPL can execute arbitrary code. Use with caution.

Invoking: Python_REPL with import scanpy as sc



Invoking: Python_REPL with import scanpy as sc
responded: It seems there was an issue with the execution of the import statement for the 'scanpy' library. I will attempt to resolve this and proceed with the task. Let's try importing the library again.

It appears that there is an issue with importing the 'scanpy' library in this environment. Without being able to import the library, I cannot proceed with plotting a UMAP of the 'pbmc' object. If the library and the necessary data were available, I would typically load the data, preprocess it, and then use the sc.pl.umap function to plot the UMAP. However, since I cannot execute the code here, I'm unable to complete this task.
```

Comment: Hi what is your question about this error message?

Comment: @mkrieger1 how can I use package like scanpy with python agent, is that even possible

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. Have you tried installing `scanpy` and importing it `as sc`? And what is `adata`?

Comment: @Grismar, yes I did "import scanpy as sc", and adata is an object that contain data. This is actually a general question that if there is any limitation for using python agent, is there a whitelist, or how to invoke some special library.

Comment: It's not clear from the code you shared that you did and it's also not clear what kind of 'object' `adata` is (pretty much anything in Python is). It's also unclear what exactly you mean by 'python agent'. From what little code you shared and the tags, it appears that you are talking about the `langchain` Python agent and that you're using the experimental branch. However, you should share enough code so that people can reproduce the issue you're having.

Comment: For future reference, don't create a new question when you want to rewrite one - just edit the one you already had.

Comment: Thanks for providing a better description. In future instances, it would be better to update the original question to avoid clutter. However, this is clear and I think I was able to provide an answer (although not really a satisfying conclusion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the `agent_executor` to list all the packages that are installed in the remote environment:

```
agent_executor.run("list all the installed packages in the environment we're running in.")
```

Result:

```
Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

                    antigravity         imaplib             seaborn
PIL                 anyio               imghdr              secrets
__future__          argparse            imp                 select
__hello__           array               importlib           selectors
__phello__          array_api_compat    inspect             session_info
_abc                ast                 io                  setuptools
_aix_support        asynchat            ipaddress           shelve
_ast                asyncio             itertools           shlex
_asyncio            asyncio_new         joblib              shutil
_bisect             asyncore            json                signal
_blake2             atexit              jsonpatch           site
_bootsubprocess     attr                jsonpointer         sitecustomize
_bz2                attrs               junk                six
_codecs             audioop             keyword             sklearn
_codecs_cn          backend_interagg    kiwisolver          smtpd
_codecs_hk          base64              langchain           smtplib
_codecs_iso2022     bdb                 langchain_experimental sndhdr
_codecs_jp          binascii            langsmith           sniffio
_codecs_kr          bisect              lib2to3             socket
_codecs_tw          bs4                 linecache           socketserver
_collections        builtins            llvmlite            soupsieve
_collections_abc    bz2                 locale              sqlalchemy
_compat_pickle      cProfile            logging             sqlite3
_compression        calendar            lxml                sre_compile
_contextvars        certifi             lzma                sre_constants
_csv                cgi                 mailbox             sre_parse
_ctypes             cgitb               mailcap             ssl
_ctypes_test        charset_normalizer  marshal             stat
_datetime           chunk               marshmallow         statistics
_decimal            cmath               math                statsmodels
_distutils_hack     cmd                 matplotlib          stdlib_list
_elementtree        code                memoisation_demo    string
_functools          codecs              mimetypes           stringprep
_hashlib            codeop              mmap                struct
_heapq              collections         modulefinder        subprocess
_imp                colorama            mpl_toolkits        sunau
_io                 colorsys            msilib              symtable
_json               compileall          msvcrt              sys
_locale             concurrent          multidict           sysconfig
_lsprof             configparser        multiprocessing     tabnanny
_lzma               contextlib          mypy                tarfile
_markupbase         contextvars         mypy_extensions     telnetlib
_md5                contourpy           mypyc               tempfile
_msi                copy                natsort             tenacity
_multibytecodec     copyreg             netrc               test
_multiprocessing    crypt               networkx            textwrap
_opcode             csv                 nntplib             this
_operator           ctypes              nt                  threading
_osx_support        curses              ntpath              threadpoolctl
_overlapped         cycler              nturl2path          time
_pickle             dataclasses         numba               timeit
_py_abc             dataclasses_json    numbers             tkinter
_pydecimal          datalore            numpy               token
_pyio               datetime            opcode              tokenize
_queue              dateutil            openai              tomllib
_random             dbm                 operator            tqdm
_sha1               decimal             optparse            trace
_sha256             difflib             os                  traceback
_sha3               dis                 packaging           tracemalloc
_sha512             distro              pandas              tty
_signal             distutils           pathlib             turtle
_sitebuiltins       doctest             patsy               turtledemo
_socket             dotenv              pdb                 types
_sqlite3            email               pickle              typing
_sre                encodings           pickletools         typing_extensions
_ssl                ensurepip           pip                 typing_inspect
_stat               enum                pipes               tzdata
_statistics         errno               pkg_resources       umap
_string             extendableenum      pkgutil             unicodedata
_strptime           faulthandler        platform            unittest
_struct             filecmp             plistlib            urllib
_symtable           fileinput           poplib              urllib3
_testbuffer         fnmatch             posixpath           uu
_testcapi           fontTools           pprint              uuid
_testconsole        fractions           profile             venv
_testimportmultiple frozenlist          pstats              warnings
_testinternalcapi   ftplib              pty                 wave
_testmultiphase     functools           py_compile          weakref
_thread             gc                  pyclbr              webbrowser
_threading_local    genericpath         pydantic            wheel
_tkinter            getopt              pydantic_core       winreg
_tokenize           getpass             pydoc               winsound
_tracemalloc        gettext             pydoc_data          working_thread
_typing             glob                pyexpat             wsgiref
_uuid               graphlib            pylab               xdrlib
_virtualenv         graphviz            pynndescent         xml
_warnings           greenlet            pyparsing           xml_stuff
_weakref            gzip                pytz                xmlrpc
_weakrefset         h11                 queue               xxsubtype
_winapi             h5py                quopri              yaml
_xxsubinterpreters  hashlib             random              yarl
_yaml               heapq               re                  zipapp
_zoneinfo           hmac                reprlib             zipfile
abc                 html                requests            zipimport
aifc                http                rlcompleter         zlib
aiohttp             httpcore            runpy               zoneinfo
aiosignal           httpx               scanpy              
anndata             idlelib             sched               
annotated_types     idna                scipy               

Enter any module name to get more help.  Or, type "modules spam" to search
for modules whose name or summary contain the string "spam".
```

It appears that `scanpy` is among them, so you should be able to use it.

```
agent_executor.run("import the scanpy package and list available functions and classes.")
```

Result:

```
Help on package scanpy:

NAME
    scanpy - Single-Cell Analysis in Python.

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    __main__
    _compat
    _settings
    _utils (package)
    _version
    cli
    datasets (package)
    experimental (package)
    external (package)
    get (package)
    logging
    metrics (package)
    neighbors (package)
    plotting (package)
    preprocessing (package)
    queries (package)
    readwrite
    sim_models (package)
    testing (package)
    tools (package)

SUBMODULES
    pl
    pp
    tl

DATA
    settings = <scanpy._settings.ScanpyConfig object>

VERSION
    1.9.6

FILE
    c:\dev\env\sandbox_311\lib\site-packages\scanpy\__init__.py
```

Since I got the same error you did initially, I tried this:

```
agent_executor.run("first import 'scanpy' and list its contents, then use 'scanpy' to plot a umap using the pbmc dataset")
```

And that actually works. AI is a bit dumb, so have to hold its hand like you would a slightly under-achieving graduate with a lot of potential.

However, this just gets you to the next roadblock: to generate the `UMAP`, it has to / wants to use `igraph` and that's actually not available in the environment. So, you'll have to figure out what available libraries could be used for this. Or perhaps tell the AI to do that for you as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can tell gpt to use tools. Or it won't use it. In the environment of gpt, it doesnt have this lib.

Just like this:

```
agent_executor = initialize_agent(
    tools=[PythonREPLTool()],
    llm=llm,
    agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
    verbose=True,
    memory=memory,
    set_debug=True,
)

st = agent_executor.invoke({"input": "I need to use Scanpy to read some mock data and provide me with the results. Please execute this using the Python REPL tool."})
```

The whole func will excute in your own computer but not openai.